# Beamer: Increase square enumerate size when using 14pt font

Tags: beamer, fonts, lists, fontsize, enumerate

I'm using beamer with 14pt and when I use enumerate or itemize it doesn't look just right:

[image: itemize example]

I'd like to have:

- The squares slightly larger
- The squares centered vertically

I have tried to play around with:

```
\setbeamertemplate{enumerate item}
{%
  \hbox{%
    \usebeamerfont*{item projected}%
    \usebeamercolor[bg]{item projected}%
    \vrule width3.25ex height3.85ex depth.4ex%
    \hskip-3.25ex%
    \hbox to3.25ex{%
      \hfil%
      \color{fg}\insertenumlabel%
      \hfil}%
  }%
}
```

which does make the bullet larger but how could I make the `\insertnumlabel` larger? And how would I center it?

Comment: Why not: `\setbeamertemplate{enumerate item}
{\usebeamercolor[bg]{item projected}\colorbox{bg}{\color{fg}\insertenumlabel}}`?

Comment: That looks good. I settled for `\footnotesize\insertnumlabel`, the default was too large for my taste. Though, it still doesn't look picture perfect since the box still is too low: http://i.imgur.com/1GeBPc8.png

Comment: Could you create a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://goo.gl/dtPzv) rather than just code snippets?

Comment: Sorry about that: https://www.writelatex.com/read/kmxtpyrrjzmh

Comment: Try `\setbeamertemplate{enumerate item} {\usebeamercolor[bg]{item projected}\raisebox{1.5pt}{\colorbox{bg}{\color{fg}\footnotesize\insertenumlabel}}}`.

Comment: Looks great. Thanks for the help. If you answer the question I can give you points.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

(Since half of the answer comes from Werner's comment I made it CW).

Use

```
\setbeamertemplate{enumerate item}{%
  \usebeamercolor[bg]{item projected}%
  \raisebox{1.5pt}{\colorbox{bg}{\color{fg}\footnotesize\insertenumlabel}}%
}
```

Complete MWE

```
\documentclass[14pt]{beamer}
\useinnertheme{rectangles}
\title{Your Presentation}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}
  \item Your introduction goes here!
\end{itemize}
\begin{enumerate}
  \item Enum
  \item Enum
  \item Enum
\end{enumerate}
\end{frame}

\setbeamertemplate{enumerate item}{%
  \usebeamercolor[bg]{item projected}%
  \raisebox{1.5pt}{\colorbox{bg}{\color{fg}\footnotesize\insertenumlabel}}%
}

\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}
  \item Your introduction goes here!
\end{itemize}
\begin{enumerate}
  \item Enum
  \item Enum
  \item Enum
\end{enumerate}
\end{frame}


\end{document}
```

Output

[image]