# Enumeration on Table of Contents Not Vertically Centered

Tags: table-of-contents, enumerate

This question is related to this post: [Beamer: Increase square enumerate size when using 14pt font](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/135550/beamer-increase-square-enumerate-size-when-using-14pt-font)

The code works perfectly in the enumeration environment but I still get the square not vertically aligned/centered in the table of contents even if I put the new code before the frame containing the \tableofcontents expression. Thanks.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}

\useinnertheme{rectangles}
\title{Your Presentation}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\section{Section 1 - Enumeration Squares Lower than Text}
\begin{frame}
   \begin{itemize}
     \item Your introduction goes here!
   \end{itemize}
    \begin{enumerate}
   \item Enum
   \item Enum
   \item Enum
 \end{enumerate}
 \end{frame}

\setbeamertemplate{enumerate item}{%
  \usebeamercolor[bg]{item projected}%
  \raisebox{1.5pt}{\colorbox{bg}{\color{fg}\footnotesize\insertenumlabel}}%
}

\section{Frame 2 - Enumeration Squares Vertically Centered}

\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}
  \item Your introduction goes here!
\end{itemize}
\begin{enumerate}
  \item Enum
  \item Enum
  \item Enum
\end{enumerate}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: the toc use other templates, e.g. `section in toc`, you can find the original definition in `beamerbaseauxtemplates.sty`, search for `\defbeamertemplate{section in toc}{square}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to insert a beamer template for the toc, just like you did for the enumerate item. You should specify `section in toc` as its first argument; I reused your code, basically, adapting it to this case:

```
\begin{frame}
\setbeamertemplate{section in toc}{\usebeamercolor[bg]{item projected}%
  \raisebox{1pt}{\colorbox{bg}{\color{fg}\footnotesize\inserttocsectionnumber}} \inserttocsection}
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}
```

This Yields:

[image]

The full code is:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\useinnertheme{rectangles}
\title{Your Presentation}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\setbeamertemplate{section in toc}{\usebeamercolor[bg]{item projected}%
  \raisebox{1pt}{\colorbox{bg}{\color{fg}\footnotesize\inserttocsectionnumber}} \inserttocsection}
\tableofcontents
\end{frame}

\section{Section 1 - Enumeration Squares Lower than Text}
\begin{frame}
   \begin{itemize}
     \item Your introduction goes here!
   \end{itemize}
    \begin{enumerate}
   \item Enum
   \item Enum
   \item Enum
 \end{enumerate}
 \end{frame}

\setbeamertemplate{enumerate item}{%
  \usebeamercolor[bg]{item projected}%
  \raisebox{1.5pt}{\colorbox{bg}{\color{fg}\footnotesize\insertenumlabel}}%
}


\section{Frame 2 - Enumeration Squares Vertically Centered}

\begin{frame}
\begin{itemize}
  \item Your introduction goes here!
\end{itemize}
\begin{enumerate}
  \item Enum
  \item Enum
  \item Enum
\end{enumerate}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

You can tweak the vertical position of the numbering changing the `\raisebox` value.

Comment: is there a way to add spacing between the squares and the text? I have tried several approaches and including the \usepackage{tocloft} as mentioned in different posts but it doesn't work. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Alan yes, you should insert a spacing command like `\hspace{5pt}` or whatever, before the \inserttocsection command