# LaTeX Beamer: two-digit numbers don't fit with enumerate square

Tags: beamer, enumerate

I'm using beamer with the inner theme "rectangles". For my presentation, I need to realize an enumeration with lots of items. The items 1 to 9 look really nice (I like the font size and the rectangle size), but the two-digit numbers are squeezed into squares of the same size and almost stick out. I think it would look better with slightly wider rectangles (they don't have to be square).

I tried to fix this using [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/135550/beamer-increase-square-enumerate-size-when-using-14pt-font), but only get needlessly big rectangles.

MWE to show the problem:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\useinnertheme{rectangles}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \begin{enumerate}
    \item These
    \item items
    \item look
    \item pretty
    \item nice
    \item \dots
    \item \dots
    \item \dots
    \item \dots
    \item \dots
    \item but two-digit numbers
    \item don't fit with the square
    \end{enumerate}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome! Try adding `\usepackage{tikz}
\setbeamertemplate{enumerate item}{%
\usebeamercolor[bg]{item projected}
\tikz[baseline=(X.base)]{\node[fill=bg,text=white,inner sep=3pt](X){\insertenumlabel};}
}` if you don't mind loading Ti*k*Z.

Comment: Thank you, that seems to be a good way (I'm using TikZ anyway, so I don't mind loading it). I changed to `\setbeamertemplate{enumerate item}{%
\usebeamercolor[bg]{item projected} \tikz[baseline=(X.base)]{\node[fill=bg,text=white,inner sep=1.2pt](X){\footnotesize\insertenumlabel};} }` and like the way it looks now. Do you want to add your comment as an answer so I can mark it as accepted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A slight modification of [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/135657/121799).

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\useinnertheme{rectangles}
\usepackage{tikz}
\setbeamertemplate{enumerate item}{%
\usebeamercolor[bg]{item projected}
\tikz[baseline=(X.base)]{\node[fill=bg,text=white,inner sep=3pt](X){\insertenumlabel};}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
    \begin{enumerate}
    \item These
    \item items
    \item look
    \item pretty
    \item nice
    \item \dots
    \item \dots
    \item \dots
    \item \dots
    \item \dots
    \item now two-digit numbers
    \item fit into the squares
    \end{enumerate}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I like this approach, because I can change the box size modifying `inner sep`