# Why are the square labels of enumeration in beamer not vertically aligned with items?

Tags: beamer, fonts, enumerate

I'm trying to make a table of contents in beamer, but it seems that the built-in square labels of enumeration are not vertically aligned with items.

As shown in the picture below, the square labels are a little bit lower than the baselines of items on the right side, especially for mixed usage of fonts in multiple languages. I wonder is there any way to have them strictly aligned.

[image]

The MWE is as follows,

```latex
\documentclass[10pt,aspectratio=43]{beamer}

\usepackage{xeCJK}
\setCJKsansfont{思源黑体}
\setbeamertemplate{sections/subsections in toc}[square]

\AtBeginSection[]
{
  \begin{frame}<beamer>
    \frametitle{\textbf{Contents}}
    \textbf{\tableofcontents[currentsection]}
  \end{frame}
}
\title{Hello World}
\author{Aha}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}

  \begin{frame}
      \titlepage
  \end{frame}   

  \section*{Contents}
  \begin{frame}
      \frametitle{\textbf{Contents}}
      \textbf{\tableofcontents}
  \end{frame}

  \section{Test Section Title 1}
  \section{Test Section Title 2}
  \section{Test Section Title 3}
  \section{测试标题1}
  \section{测试标题2}
  \section{测试标题3}
\end{document}
```

The CJK font used in the example is an open-sourced font created by Adobe, which can be downloaded through https://github.com/adobe-fonts/source-han-sans/raw/release/OTF/SourceHanSansSC.zip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to TeX.SX! You can use [this approach](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/436513/47927) (which you can apply if you want this also to work for enumerations) and customize these boxes using Ti*k*Z. This way, the boxes should be aligned with the baseline of the text. (I changed the Chinese font to one that I had installed on my system, but it should not make any bigger difference.)

```
\documentclass[10pt,aspectratio=43]{beamer}

\usepackage{xeCJK}
\setCJKsansfont{Noto Sans CJK SC}
%\setbeamertemplate{sections/subsections in toc}[square]

\usepackage{tikz}
\setbeamertemplate{sections/subsections in toc}{%
  \usebeamercolor[bg]{section number projected}%
  \tikz[baseline=(X.base)]{\node[fill=bg,text=white,inner sep=3pt](X){\inserttocsectionnumber};} \inserttocsection%
}

\AtBeginSection[]
{
  \begin{frame}<beamer>
    \frametitle{\textbf{Contents}}
    \textbf{\tableofcontents[currentsection]}
  \end{frame}
}
\title{Hello World}
\author{Aha}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}

  \begin{frame}
      \titlepage
  \end{frame}   

  \section*{Contents}
  \begin{frame}
      \frametitle{\textbf{Contents}}
      \textbf{\tableofcontents}
  \end{frame}

  \section{Test Section Title 1}
  \section{Test Section Title 2}
  \section{Test Section Title 3}
  \section{测试标题1}
  \section{测试标题2}
  \section{测试标题3}
\end{document}
```

Note that the Chinese characters are larger than capital letters of the Latin font you use. Therefore, you will always have an optical height difference between both scripts. You could try to use just one font for both scripts. Source Han Sans SC should cover Latin characters as well and the glyphs of the different scripts may be better aligned in terms of vertical alignment and size.

[image]